# C++ Iterate from the second element of a map

Tags: c++, stl, multimap

I have a `std::multimap` on which I am iterating using a forward iterator.

```
std::multimap<int,char>::iterator it;
for(it=map.begin();it!=map.end();++it) {
    // do something
}
```

Now I need to treat the first element differently and start iterating from the second element of the map. How do I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
std::multimap<int,char>::iterator it;

for(it = std::next(map.begin()); it != map.end(); ++it) {
    // do something
}
```

This is C++11 only. You'll need to include `<iterator>`.

The other option is obvious, but less pretty:

```
it = map.begin();
++it;
for(; it != map.end(); ++it) {
    // do something
}
```

Take a look at [`std::advance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance), too.

Answer (score 6):

Seems it looks shorter

```
it = ++map.begin();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
std::multimap<int,char>::iterator it = map.begin();
//treat it here
++it
for(;it!=map.end();++it) {

}
```

Comment: that was just a hint, he seemed not to know about how to do it

Answer (score 1):

```
for(bool First=true, it=map.begin();it!=map.end();++it) {
    if (First) { do something; First=false; }
    else { do something else; }
}
```

or, if you prefer:

```
iterator it=map.begin();
if (it!=map.end()) { do something; ++it; }
for (; it!=map.end(); ++it) { do something }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `it = map.begin()` in the for-initializer to `it = map.begin(), ++it`.

Comment: That is, if you don't have C++11. If you do, the solution from @jrok is better.

Answer (score 0):

you can directly use this

```
unordered_map<int,int> map;

n = 1
auto it = std::next(map.begin(), n);

int key = it->first
```